# How do you pull more than 100 rows from Google Sheet to Excel via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from a Google Sheet to Excel via VBA. I have the following code that works, however, it only pulls up to row 100 and I would need at least another 100 more rows.

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(SheetURL, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
     .WebTables = "1"
     .Refresh False
End With
```

Comment: https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-Scripting/Load-from-google-sheet-limited-to-100-rows/td-p/874206

Comment: @braX problem solved, thank you!